# Second connection to socket fails

Tags: c#, sockets, azure, actor, azure-service-fabric

I made a service fabric app that uses an actor service to create a message channel with the client application via Socket.

The client app runs an Asynchronous Server Socket like in this example https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/fx6588te(v=vs.85).aspx and my actor connects it using client ip address like in this scheme:

```
public static void StartClient(byte[] i_address, string i_message)
{
        // Connect to a remote device.
        try
        {
            ActorEventSource.Current.Message("Creating socket");
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(i_address), port);
            ActorEventSource.Current.Message("IPAddress created");
            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            ActorEventSource.Current.Message("Client created");
            client.Connect(remoteEP);
            ActorEventSource.Current.Message("Client connected");
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(i_message);

            ActorEventSource.Current.Message("Sending: " + i_message);

            client.Send(byteData);

            ActorEventSource.Current.Message("SENT");

            // Release the socket.
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ActorEventSource.Current.Message(e.ToString());
        }
}
```

When it is running using local ip address it works correctly, but when it works using public ip address it works correctly once.

The second connection attemp fails on `client.Connect(remoteEP);` with

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed

Comment: If you want to work with Remote IP, you have to change router' settings. There s no problem in your code.

Comment: I had my router port forwarding configured for my ip and used port, should I do something more?

Comment: If you would share more results I can guess the problem. Did you make router' setting for both routers? @Shkire

Comment: Now i'm testing client and app on the same machine, so I think this can't be the problem. In addition, client app doesn't answer to actor message, it's a one way communication